# Convert Bitmap to Thumbnail

Tags: c#

I want to generate a thumbnail from an image in C#. How do I do that?

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap or a WPF image?

Comment: input params, desired output type, anything?

Comment: please supply more details including what you have tried already

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) class actually has a [GetThumbnailImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx) method. Example usage:

```
var filename = "fb.png";

using(var image = Image.FromFile(filename))
{
    using(var thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(20/*width*/, 40/*height*/, null, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        thumbnail.Save("thumb.png");
    }
}
```

This will generate a 20x40px thumbnail version of fb.png and save it to thumb.png.