# Display small image catalog in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Hi I want to put products to a catalog, How i can  crop the  picture to small and save the small and the orginal?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try look here:

[C# Thumbnail Image With GetThumbnailImage](http://www.dotnetperls.com/getthumbnailimage)

or here:

[Convert Bitmap to Thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4545273/735864)

[Create thumbnail and reduce image size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/684092/735864)

[Create thumbnail image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2808887/735864)

**update**

For example you can save the image to a folder and then you can do something like this:

```
var filename = "sourceImage.png";

using(var image = Image.FromFile(filename))
{
    using(var thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(20/*width*/, 40/*height*/, null, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        thumbnail.Save("thumb.png");
    }
}
```

**update**

to resize proportionally try something like this:

```
public Bitmap ProportionallyResizeBitmap (Bitmap src, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{

// original dimensions
int w = src.Width;
int h = src.Height;

// Longest and shortest dimension
int longestDimension = (w>h)?w: h;
int shortestDimension = (w<h)?w: h;

// propotionality
float factor = ((float)longestDimension) / shortestDimension;

// default width is greater than height
double newWidth = maxWidth;
double newHeight = maxWidth/factor;

// if height greater than width recalculate
if ( w < h )
{
    newWidth = maxHeight / factor;
    newHeight = maxHeight;
}

// Create new Bitmap at new dimensions
Bitmap result = new Bitmap((int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);
using ( Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)result) )
g.DrawImage(src, 0, 0, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight);

return result;
}
```

Comment: Can I reduce the image immediately or only after I've saved?

Comment: can i cut the image proportionately without knowing the original image size ?